# It's possible to set UpperCase by default in the table window project of SqlServer?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Can I define the UpperCase of the strings inserted at design time as defoult?
I would understand if I can do it without using triggers

[image]

Comment: Dear, I delete my answer because, you want store always UPPER value and not prevent the other value, so check constraint is unuseful. I think is not possible your goal.

Comment: Not possible via Table Window Creation Pane

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best is to do this in the Application

2nd best is to use update trigger

3rd alternative is to use computed column

Comment: Perfectly agree with you, in fact the question I ask if it is possible. 
Generally I do as you suggest